# How can I remove the single sign-on setting in the Tridion MMC

Tags: web8.5, mmc

I used SSO in the past and now no longer wish to use it, how can I remove the SSO value from the **UserName Qualifier** in the MMC?

I just need to set it to a blank, but the MMC always wants you to set a value for this field. Is there a way to make this value blank again?

[image: SDL web8.5 MMC]

Comment: Please **edit** your question and supply the additional information in there. Do not try to use an answer for that, see also https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable SSO, I would suggest reverting all the changes specified in [SDL documentation.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-8A1E3956-E773-41ED-8660-55B0C44A7E4B#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-97E4D490-2D32-46EE-ADDE-E30513A1C3D9.xml&docid=GUID-8A1E3956-E773-41ED-8660-55B0C44A7E4B&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-8A1E3956-E773-41ED-8660-55B0C44A7E4B)

That alone should effectively disable it, no mater the value in MMC snap-in console. As for the value, MMC snap-in changes `TridionContentManager.config` in background, so you can always change it by yourself. For us, we disabled it by leaving SSO value in `UserName Qualifier` field, and by reverting all the other changes in configurations.

Comment: Many thanks, SSO has already been disabled and that works okay for connecting to the CMS without SSO,but for some reason I cannot use Templatebuilder and Content Porter and it seem to me they are attempting to use the value in this filed as if we still have SSO enabled.  I already checked (TridionContentmanager.confg) and this value was not specified in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the SSO integration, you must specify a User Name Qualifier and that is why you cannot leave it empty in the configuration.

These SSO settings are used by the `SsoAgentModule`. If you want to disable the SSO integration, you will have to remove that HTTP module from the CM website (and ensure an alternative authorization method is configured).

If you’re getting problems only for certain web applications/services, you should check if the `SsoAgentModule` is also removed from the individual web apps within the CM website (`templating`, `webservices`, etc.)

Comment: But this does not help me remove the `User Name Qualifier`, it seem once you have an entry in there you can not remove it as it does not show up in  the `TridionContentManager.config` file, you can change it but not remove it., I was just wondering where that data is stored. However it seem not to stop you from configuring an alternative authorization method.Many thanks Rick.